# Оранжевый - было ли в русском другое название для этого цвета?

Tags: этимология, словообразование

Слово "оранжевый" заимствовано в русский язык и, судя по всему, связано с цветом апельсина - orange.
Любопытно, было ли в русском языке свое название этого цвета?

Answer (score 1):

Немного не так. Апельсин был назван по цвету. А сам цвет - по фамилии герцогов Оранжских, родовым цветом которых он был.
А вот было ли в русском другое название... Откровенно говоря - не знаю. Но по косвенным признакам полагаю, что не было. Об этом говорит уже то, что такое заимствование вряд ли бы произошло при "живом" слове. И в близкородственных славянмких оно не сохранилось. Украинское (а также польское и сербское) "помаранчевий" - такое же заимствование, хотя допускаю, что оно более раннее, -и таким образом могло быть и в русском.

Есть ещё предположение, что все оранжевое могло именоваться рыжим. Сейчас "рыжий" по некоторым классификациям считается одним из оттенков оранжевого.

Comment: да, точно! скорее всего рыжий и был, либо желтый.

Answer (score 1):

В  диалектах (у некоторых жителей сёл Белгородской области на границе с Украиной) есть слово жёлтогорячий.

Comment: Да, это слово известно. Не только там. Но врядли оно могло быть исконным для обозначения оранжевого.